# Eclipse does not allow me to open projects in my workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

My Eclipse is an X86 version that came with an ADT Bundle download,I have pointed it to my workspace when it prompted me for the choice of workspace when it starts.When I try to open a project,it throws the following error:

```
   Failed to read the project description file (.project) for 'tess-two'.  The file has   
   been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not   
   function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state.
```

My previous Eclipse installation had deleted the Manifest file of atleast one app as far as I know.

The contents of all of my projects seem to have been magically deleted by Eclipse when it crashed after the system restarted.All my files are gone.i have tried opening the files with Notepad++ and they are all empty.Why would Eclipse do that,I do not even have any backups.

Comment: http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/creatingAndroidProject.html

Answer (score 0):

Check whether that project is available in your hard disk. If yes, import that to any other workspace. It MAY fix it.

Comment: My previous Eclipse deleted all my files,not the files but all their contents

Comment: Do you have the class & resource files? or it deleted all the files?

Comment: Then it is not reusable. It is Possible only if you have any back up!

Comment: My Eclipse did it again,i have backups now,I copied my projects to another workspace to resolve an issue and it deleted projects in the new workspace

Comment: Try to get a new copy of eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the workspace location in eclipse and create one more work space and import your projects..